# How to use xpath to select a value in a drop down list located in a particular row?

Tags: html, xpath, selenium-webdriver, html-table, row

I am testing a page using selenium web driver. I have rows of data that represent 'requests', and in the last column of each of those rows the user can click a drop down list (with the option to either approve or reject) element that allows them to 'approve' or 'reject' the request.

I need to be able to select the approve option on the drop down list of a row whose 'Name' column is equal to a variable (in this instance say the variable is 'John').

In this test the user will be approving 'John's' request by selecting approve. How do I use xpath to ensure I am selecting the correct drop down element for the right person (right row)? Will I need to include a select element within an xpath somehow?

An example of the select element method to select a drop down element:

```
new SelectElement(this.Driver.FindElement(By.Name("orm")).FindElement(By.Name("Tutors"))).SelectByText(tutorName);

<form name="RequestsForm" action="SubmitRequest.aspx" method="POST">
<h2 class="blacktext" align="center">Course approvals</h2>
<table class="cooltable" width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="heading">
<b>Name</b>
</td>
<td class="heading">
<b>Request Date</b>
</td>
<td class="heading">
<b>Approved</b>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
John
<input id="T1" type="text" value="888" name="T1">
</td>
<td>1/3/2015</td>
<td>
<select id="D1" class="selecttext" size="1" name="D1">
<option>?</option>
<option value="Approved">Approved</option>
<option>Rejected</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using XPath, this gets the *position* where the `Name` column is in your table:

```xml
count(//table[@class='cooltable']/tbody/tr[1]/td[b = 'Name']/preceding-sibling::td)+1
```

You can use that position to get the corresponding table cell in the other columns. This selects the corresponding `td` in the second row (where the `...` represent the expression above):

```xml
//table[@class='cooltable']/tbody/tr[2]/td[count( ... )+1]
```

Appending `/text()` will extract the text (with spaces). Using `normalize-space()` will trim the text so you can compare it with `John`:

```xml
normalize-space(//table[@class='cooltable']/tbody/tr[2]/td[count( ... )+1]/text()) = 'John'
```

To select only the `tr` which contains `John` in the `Name` column, you leave only the `td` in the predicate. Now it returns a node-set of all `tr` which match the predicate text = `John`:

```xml
//table[@class='cooltable']/tbody/tr[normalize-space(td[count( ... )+1]/text()) = 'John']
```

Finally, if you append `//select/option[@value='Approved']` to that expression, you will select the option with the `Approved` attribute in the context of that `tr`. Here is the full XPath expression:

```xml
//table[@class='cooltable']/tbody/tr[normalize-space(td[count(//table[@class='cooltable']/tbody/tr[1]/td[b = 'Name']/preceding-sibling::td)+1]/text()) = 'John']//select/option[@value='Approved']
```